# How to generate Google maps release key for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, key

How to generate Google Api release key? In development environment I used debug.keystore to generate debug key. But I'm now about to release the Android app to the market. So how to generate the release key?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is documented [here - Obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey).

Answer (score 0):

Googled a lot, till got one for me.

Here's how the command should look like in the command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin> keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\Andranik\.android\MyKeystore
```

No copy the MD5 and go [here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup). Here you get the apiKey.

Replace your key with `HERE_YOUR_KEY` and here you go.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/myGMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="HERE_YOUR_KEY"/>
```